# Menu inflater not showing in emulator

Tags: android

menu is not showing in my emulator.menu code is implemented in home.java class,inflator usess menu but is not showing on emulator .

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.home);
}

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater Inflater = getMenuInflater();
    Inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu, menu);
    return(super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu));
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.logout) {
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        editor.remove("logged");
        editor.commit();
        finish();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Vipul Shah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/758104/vipul-shah) said you should change this line:

```
Inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu, menu);
```

to

```
Inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
```

After that - replace your `menu.xml` to `res/menu` instead of `res/layout`.

Then you should obviously return true instead of returning results of super's methods.
Your code should be like that:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater Inflater = getMenuInflater();
    Inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.logout :
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        editor.remove("logged");
        editor.commit();
        finish();
        return true;
    default: return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Change this

```
Inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu, menu);
```

> To This

```
Inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
```

Put your menu.xml in **res/menu** folder.